# how should i add python path in wsgi.py when using virtualenv

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a django website using apache2.4, mod_wsgi on ubuntu 14.04.
The problem is that my wsgi.py file is unable to import django. this obviously means that i have not set python path for the virtualenv. But i am a little confused as to how to add python path of virtuaenv's site-packages. 
my wsgi.py is:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/sp/webapps')
sys.path.append('/home/sp/webapps/ilog_dev')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ilog_dev.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

so the question is how should i add the virtualenv's site-package to python path

Comment: See the activate_this recipe towards end of http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `path/to/virtualenv/activate` before doing anything? Or maybe you didn't use virtualenv's python instead of global python.

Comment: You can't use the 'activate' command line script with Apache/mod_wsgi easily as you generally don't have ability to change the scripts that startup Apache.

Comment: yes as the answer suggested, i only had to add this line  sys.path.append('/path/to/my/venv/')